# How to extract the first instance of a sublist element using a repeated pattern?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
l = [['act137L', 'act222J1', 'act45k', 'bac003', 'bac19004', 'cob55C37'],
     ['act3947', 'act658ll', 'act3FjL', 'bac57D73', 'cob00091', 'cob1A4']]
```

and I would like to put the first instance of `'act...'`, `'bac...'`, and `'cob...'` from each sublist into another list to obtain:

```
l2 = [['act137L', 'bac003', 'cob55C37'], ['act3947', 'bac57D73', 'cob00091']]
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

This function should work:

```
def get_firsts(the_lists, terms):
    ret_lists = []
    for a_list in the_lists:
        new_list = []
        rest_terms = terms[:]
        while rest_terms:
            for val in a_list:
                for term in rest_terms[:]:
                    if val.startswith(term):
                        new_list.append(val)
                        rest_terms.remove(term)
        ret_lists.append(new_list)
    return ret_lists
```

Use it as such:

```
>>> get_firsts(l, ['act','bac','cob'])
[['act137L', 'bac003', 'cob55C37'], ['act3947', 'bac57D73', 'cob00091']]
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work as posted. It works when removing the while statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) with first three letters as key to collect the values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [['act137L', 'act222J1', 'act45k', 'bac003', 'bac19004', 'cob55C37'],
     ['act3947', 'act658ll', 'act3FjL', 'bac57D73', 'cob00091', 'cob1A4']]

def first_items(l):
    res = []
    for sublist in l:
        d = OrderedDict()
        for x in sublist:
            d.setdefault(x[:3], x)
        res.append(list(d.values()))

    return res

print(first_items(l))
```

Output:

```
[['act137L', 'bac003', 'cob55C37'], ['act3947', 'bac57D73', 'cob00091']]
```

In above [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) sets the value if key is not present in the `dict`. If key already exists it doesn't change the `dict` thus the first value set is preserved.

If you know that items with same prefix are always next to each other in the lists you can use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

res = [[next(g) for _, g in groupby(sublist, lambda x: x[:3])] for sublist in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List comprehension:

```
l2 = [[j[i] for i in range(len(j)) if j[i][:3] not in ''.join(k for k in j[:i])] for j in l]
```

This adds the elements only to the newly constructed sublist if no such element was added yet.